# When to use 'name' and when to use 'as'

Tags: layout, blocks, theme, magento-1

I've found that when trying to use the `unsetChild` method, sometimes I have to use the 'name' attribute and others 'as'. It seems that if a block is added normally, you use 'as' but if it is  added to a block using the `append` method, you may have to use 'name'. Is this assumption correct?

What is the reasoning behind this and is there a standard way to understand which attribute you should use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Block can always be referenced by `name`. Alias (`as`) is used to simplify the long name of a block and the only differs with the scope. `Name` has to be unique within the page and `alias` within a parent block.

Comment: I'm afraid none of that is true. In template, you cannot reference a block by its name if it has an alias set. You can only use the alias.As for the uniqueness of alias, quite the opposite is true -- alias was introduced to make it possible for a different block to be rendered without changing template.

Comment: @JanTomka has given the main use of aliases. It should be pointed out that while the statement that *"you cannot reference a block by its name if it has an alias set"* is generally true, there is a method named `getBlockHtml()` which is sometimes used to render blocks by name.

Answer (score 6):

When you use **as**, you can call **$this->getChildHtml("as_value")** on the phtml template.

The **name** must be unique, and can be used for *< reference >* blocks, *< remove >*, etc.

For example (catalog.xml):

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
</block>
```

If you open catalog/product/view.phtml you'll see:

```
<div class="product-img-box">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
</div>
```

You see? as="media", and then $this->getChildHtml('media')...

Answer (score 5):

Nobody has answered the particular question about `unsetChild` yet. Methods related to **children** of a block **always** refer to child blocks by alias, which is only known to the parent and unlike the name, not globally unique.

But if the block was created without defining an alias, the alias defaults to the name.

So in short, if the child block has an explicit alias, you must use the alias. If not, use the name.

Aliases are given by `as="..."` if the block was created as child block via XML, or by action parameter if they were moved around or dynamically added with methods like `append()`, `insert()` or `setChild()`.