# unable to insert widget in product detail page

Tags: magento-1, theme

I am developing the Magento theme I am trying to add the widget in the product detail page through layout so that I can make it installable but I am unable to add the widget. here is the following code I am using the embed widget. please help me, friends

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="product_additional_data">
            <block type="sharer/sharer" name="sharing_widget" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

and in `view.phtml` this code is used to fetch reference

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data');
```

Comment: did you try another block? Are you sure your widget is working and the mistake is in the layout.xml? It looks correct for me. If you don't need to specify a template

Comment: yes i have have tried it with reference name="addto" it addto cart block

Comment: i have check this widget with add widget in cms page and it showing in cms page

Comment: afaik you have to take the name as the reference name `product.info.additional`, did you try that? :) This is described here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/781/when-to-use-name-and-when-to-use-as/782#782

Comment: still its not working

Comment: Try to add another block `<block type="core/text" name="mytext"><action method="setText"><text>Das ist mein Text.</text></action></block>`

Comment: its also not working i can't see this text anywhere after update xml

Comment: i put that code in reference block name="product.info.additional"

Comment: Then your reference is broken. And you can edit yur comment's so there aren't that much. The block with the name `product.info.additional` or `product_additional_data` doesn't exist

Comment: but i can see view.phtml is loading module by this name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the block is defined in catalog.xml:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
```

I believe you want to use its `name` in the `reference`, and the `as` alias as parameter to `getChildHtml()`.

Layout update:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.additional">
            <block type="sharer/sharer" name="sharing_widget" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

view.phtml:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data');
```

If that doesn't do the trick, to debug the whole thing a bit, you may want to `Mage::log($name)` in

`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Additional.php:getChildHtmlList()`

If `sharing_widget` is there, the widget itself outputs no HTML.

Comment: You might want to replace the <default> tag with <catalog_product_view> because there is no reason to parse this xml section an all pages.

Comment: True that, answer updated.