# Magento 2 Layout XML <container> "as" attribute

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, containers

What exactly is the "`as`" attribute in `<container>` for in a layout xml?
When do I need to reference this one contrary to "`name`"?

```
<container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
```

Comment: Check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Comment: I already did. "An alias name that serves as identifier in the scope of the parent element.". Unfortunately this sentence is not enough for me to understand it.

Comment: Then check -> http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/781/when-to-use-name-and-when-to-use-as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` attribute is unique and will serve to merge layouts together.

The `as` is a short way for the same block, has to be unique in context, and can serve to get the block.

For exemple (in `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::getChildBlock`) :

```
$this->getChildBlock('search_result_list');
```