# Magento 2 - block name vs as name

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, xml, frontend

I've been doing some work in **Magento 2** and have been overwriting some modules i've installed ( on the frontend ).

However today i've just come across something that I've not encountered before. The module I've been using has a block inside of it which has the following:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Vender\Module\Block\Catalog\Related" name="posts.tab" as="blog.posts"
               template="Vender_Module::catalog/posts.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

It sets its name:

> posts.tab

and then uses the ***as*** to allow it to be called via:

> as="blog.posts"

When i tried to reference the block to be removed using the ***as*** name I noticed that it wasn't removing it from the page:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <referenceBlock as="blog.posts" remove="true"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

so i went to see what the page actually called in on the frontend ( just incase it was being renamed somewhere else or wasn't using the posts.tab name ) - the block name is being called in with **posts.tab** , which is fine as i can just reference that block to remove it. That worked fine.

But my question is, why isn't the block being pulled through using **as** and instead being pulled through using the ***name***.

Secondly what is the point in the **as**, because obviously blocks can't have conflicting names anyway and should be unique - but i might be totally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance it seems like the as attribute is useless (unless it's used elsewhere), I don't think it makes a difference if it's called via name or the alias so it's up to the developer to choose what to use - just note that if an alias is set you will need to use that when calling `getChildHtml`.

Personally I'll only use alias to shorten a long block name and/or to make it easily readable when rendering it via a template. For example if `checkout.header.logo.text` needs to be used as `logo.text` and `header.logo.text` are already used, you could then use the alias `logoText` on all the blocks. This wouldn't affect the rendering of the other blocks using the same alias unless they are set in the same layout handle and reference.

**TL:DR** It doesn't make much of a difference, it's more for readability/shortening names.

#### Notes

This M1 question has a bit more info to - [When to use 'name' and when to use 'as'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/781/when-to-use-name-and-when-to-use-as)

I'm not sure if this applies to M2 but in M1 there was at least one argument called `alias` which used the `as` attribute, I think it was related to inserting or unsetting blocks.

According to Fabian Schmengler: "If the block was created without defining an alias, the alias defaults to the name." That is referring to M1 but I presume the same thing applies to M2.

Comment: Just now on 2.3.1 I couldn't getChildHtml by name because the block had "as" alias. Only after deleting the alias I could get the block in a template.

Comment: Good point @TheKitMurkit - I've added a bit to my answer that states "if an alias is set you will need to use that when calling getChildHtml.". Thanks.